# Better to change Alt to Ctrl or Ctrl to Alt, using same keyboard for Mac & Windows

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

So I just got myself a Windows 10 PC.

I use the same [keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000A6PPOK)/monitor to switch between them.

I also have a Chromebook that I use.

In OS X, the keyboard's <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key.

So sometimes to copy/paste, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on OS X and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Windows. My hands are confused.

I'm trying to figure out if I should have the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key stay at the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. (So I would have to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> into <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on OS X)

Or, should I change <kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows 10?

P.S. Maybe the right solution is a KVM?

Answer (score 1):

There is an application called Karabiner, formerly KeyRemap4MacBook, which allowed you to very easily customize your keyboard shortcuts. Many people used this in order to have Windows-style keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

OS X can also handle it, as another, less complex option. In **System Preferences,** under **Keyboard,** click **Modifier Keys** and you can easily swap <kbd>Command</kbd> to act as <kbd>Control</kbd>

[image]

An option for modifying your keyboard on Windows is [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/). It follows a similar idea to Karabiner

[image]